# lower bound on $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have the following expression$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$ What are some (tight) lower bounds on this expression ?
I need this (or these) bound(s) in function of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is a pretty tight lower bound for itself. If you want a bound with properties that this doesn't have, you'll need to specify _which_ properties you desire.

Comment: A less tight lower bound is $0$, but you probably figured that out already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One helpful lower bound is
$$
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \geq \sqrt 2\min\{|a|,|b|\}
$$
More generally, for any $p > 1$, we have
$$
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \geq \sqrt{\frac{(a^{2/p} + b^{2/p})^p}{2^{p-1}}}
$$
as a consequence of Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 3):

One lower bound (derived from Cauchy-Schwarz) is
$$\sqrt{a^2+ b^2} \geq \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(|a|+|b|) .$$

Comment: This is also derivable from $2(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2$

Comment: By the way, we have $(|a|+|b|)/2 \geq (|a|+|b| - | |a|-|b| |)/2 = \min(|a|,|b|)$ so Omnomnomnom's first inequality is implied...

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here is a visualization of the bounds obtained so far.
For a given radius $R$,

- the blue circle is the set of $(x, y)$ where
  $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le R$,
- the green square is the set where
  $ \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(|x|+|y|) \le R$, and
- the yellow "cross" (which extends infinitely in four directions)
  is the set where  $\sqrt 2\min\{|x|,|y|\} \le R$.

The containments "blue circle $\subset$ green square $\subset$ yellow cross" correspond
to the inequalities
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}  \ge \frac1{\sqrt{2}} (|x|+|y|) \ge \sqrt 2\min 
\{|x|,|y|\} \, .
$$

[image]

Comment: Neat!${}{}{}{}{}$